# iOS how to reconnect to BLE device in background?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process

There are many related questions but (apparently) no answers. SO...

My iOS app *does* get updates from my BLE device while the app is in background. If I lose touch with the BLE device, then in `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:` I call -`[CBCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:]` -- otherwise I will never reconnect to the lost peripheral. Then I call [(re)call -`[CBCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:]`.

Logging shows me that the `didDisconnectPeripheral` call, and its contained calls, are both happening *while in background*. However, the reconnect only happens when the app wakes up from background.

So I am able to communicate with the connected BLE device while in background (yay!) but not to reconnect. This is quite important to my app, and (one would think) to other apps. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Paul was correct, that I did not need to cancel the connection, and that I did not need to rescan, *and* that all I needed to do was call connectPeripheral. BUT... what I was not doing was this:

```
_manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)];
```

I was passing nil for the queue, which meant my CBCentralManagerDelegate callbacks were running on the main thread.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to cancel the connection - it is already disconnected
You don't need to rescan for the peripheral - you have already identified your peripheral.

In `didDisconnectPeripheral` you can simply call

```
[central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
```

Core Bluetooth will reconnect once the peripheral is visible again

A complete sample is here - https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. In fact, using connectPeripheral (instead of re-calling scanForPeripherals) my app does not reconnect even if it is still in the foreground. The connection is never re-established. Whereas if I call scanForPeripheral in didDisconnectPeripheral, I *do* reconnect if in foreground, but still not in background. Grr.

Comment: The device is a TI SensorTag, FWIW.

Comment: Ok.  Sensor tags are annoying - they shut down after a few minutes, so I am not sure if this is your problem.  iOS devices are also hard to work with because they change MAC address every few minutes.  I have a sensor tag, so I will have a play around and see what happens.  It may take me a day or two...

Comment: Thank you Paul. I don't think it has to do with any auto-disconnect. This is me deliberately disconnecting (or walking 50m away) in order to force the loss of connection. I'll keep plugging away too. Must be a solved problem.. or else everybody is in the same pickle.

Comment: The problem with re-calling scanForPeripheral is that all the (irrelevant) peripherals that I found and ignored on startup are re-found and have to be re-ignored. Leading me to thing that re-scanning must not be the Right Thing To Do. Also, mengxiangjian's suggestion did not help. (See above.)

Comment: On a related topic (yes this is getting looong) I try to scan only for peripherals with TI accelerometer service by calling `[central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"F000AA10-0451-4000-B000-000000000000"]] options:nil]`. But I discover nothing when I do this; I do find the SensorTag when I pass in a nil for the first param.

Comment: Once you have identified the peripheral you simply be able to reconnect using its UUID (assuming it isn't an iOS device that changes as per my previous comment)

Comment: How do you do that? The only connect method I see takes a CBPeripheral object as its parameter. (That is the connect method you suggested first.)

Comment: You can pass the uuid to `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` method on cbcentralmanager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64820/discussion-between-paulw11-and-andrew-duncan).

Comment: More info at http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/538/t/263495.aspx

This suggests that background connecting only works when you specify advertised services. But apparently the TI device does *not* advertise its services. At least not with default firmware. Hmm.

Comment: If the central resets, the peripheral objects won't be valid anymore.

Comment: Calling connectPeripheral the CoreBluetooth will reconnect when the peripheral is visible again. It does not drain the battery?

Comment: Not really. The device is just listening for the peripheral's advertisement, not transmitting anything.

Answer (score 3):

I know you probably have everything figured out already. I my self stumbled on this issue as well. Doing the following alone would not completely solve the problem (at least for me):
`[central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];`

Instead of "nil" for the options, you will need to provide "options" in the above method. There are other things you need to set up as well (such as info.plist for your app).
After reading Apple's instruction on how to enable background bluetooth operation for an App. I was able to get it working and receiving events for connect,disconnect,update etc., even scan can work in the back ground. Not to repeat everything what the Apple document has written about, you can take a look at the following link:
[Core Bluetooth Background Processing for iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me, the key was passing the appropriate parameter for the queue, as noted above. However, the options are definitely relevant too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In tab "Capabilities" -> Background Modes, choose the "Users Bluetooth LE accessories" and "Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory".I am not sure it can work, but you can have a try.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already has Uses Bluetooth LE accessories checked. I added Acts As, but it did not change things. Good idea though. One should always try things that *should not* work. Because they might work!